# Smooth and Riemannian metrics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Can someone explain to me what is the relation between "smooth metric" and "Riemannian metric".

Do we have an implication or an equivalence between the two notions.

Thanks for any answer

Comment: I think that they refer to the same thing, but you should give some context. (One difference may be that a "smooth metric" is not necessarily positive definite, while a "Riemannian metric" definitely is).

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold).

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde : they say (smooth) Riemannian metric ... so Riemannian implies that it is smooth ??

Comment: Yes, Riemannian is smooth, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929462/why-riemannian-metrics-have-to-be-smooth?rq=1). For the converse question, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894694/smooth-manifold-with-metric-became-riemannian-manifold?rq=1).